# What's wrong with how I save a vector of AVFrames as mp4 video using the h264 encoder?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am trying to encode a vector of AVFrames to an MP4 file using the h264 codec.

The code runs without errors but both when I try to open the saved video file with the windows media and adobe Media Encoded they it says that it is in an unsupported format.

I went through it with a debugger and everything seemed to work fine.

---

This is the function I used to saved the video:

```
void SaveVideo(std::string& output_filename, std::vector<AVFrame> video)
{
    // Initialize FFmpeg
    avformat_network_init();

    // Open the output file context
    AVFormatContext* format_ctx = nullptr;
    int ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&format_ctx, nullptr, nullptr, output_filename.c_str());
    if (ret < 0) {
        wxMessageBox("Error creating output context: ");
        wxMessageBox(av_err2str(ret));
        return;
    }

    // Open the output file
    ret = avio_open(&format_ctx->pb, output_filename.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening output file: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Create the video stream
    const AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!codec) {
        std::cerr << "Error finding H.264 encoder" << std::endl;
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    AVStream* stream = avformat_new_stream(format_ctx, codec);
    if (!stream) {
        std::cerr << "Error creating output stream" << std::endl;
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Set the stream parameters
    stream->codecpar->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    stream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    stream->codecpar->width =video.front().width;
    stream->codecpar->height = video.front().height;
    stream->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    stream->codecpar->bit_rate = 400000;
    AVRational framerate = { 1, 30};
    stream->time_base = av_inv_q(framerate);

    // Open the codec context
    AVCodecContext* codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    codec_ctx->codec_tag = 0;
    codec_ctx->time_base = stream->time_base;
    codec_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    if (!codec_ctx) {
        std::cout << "Error allocating codec context" << std::endl;
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, stream->codecpar);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cout << "Error setting codec context parameters: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }
    AVDictionary* opt = NULL;
    ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, &opt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        wxMessageBox("Error opening codec: ");
        wxMessageBox(av_err2str(ret));
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Allocate a buffer for the frame data
    AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        std::cerr << "Error allocating frame" << std::endl;
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    frame->format = codec_ctx->pix_fmt;
    frame->width = codec_ctx->width;
    frame->height = codec_ctx->height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error allocating frame buffer: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Allocate a buffer for the converted frame data
    AVFrame* converted_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!converted_frame) {
        std::cerr << "Error allocating converted frame" << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    converted_frame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    converted_frame->width = codec_ctx->width;
    converted_frame->height = codec_ctx->height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(converted_frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error allocating converted frame buffer: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Initialize the converter
    SwsContext* converter = sws_getContext(
        codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, codec_ctx->pix_fmt,
        codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
        SWS_BICUBIC, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr
    );
    if (!converter) {
        std::cerr << "Error initializing converter" << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Write the header to the output file
    ret = avformat_write_header(format_ctx, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error writing header to output file: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
        sws_freeContext(converter);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Iterate over the frames and write them to the output file
    int frame_count = 0;
    for (auto& frame: video) {
         {
            // Convert the frame to the output format
            sws_scale(converter,
                srcFrame.data, srcFrame.linesize, 0, srcFrame.height,
                converted_frame->data, converted_frame->linesize
            );

            // Set the frame properties
            converted_frame->pts = av_rescale_q(frame_count, stream->time_base, codec_ctx->time_base);
            frame_count++;
            //converted_frame->time_base.den = codec_ctx->time_base.den;
            //converted_frame->time_base.num = codec_ctx->time_base.num;
            // Encode the frame and write it to the output
            ret = avcodec_send_frame(codec_ctx, converted_frame);
            if (ret < 0) {
                std::cerr << "Error sending frame for encoding: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
                av_frame_free(&frame);
                av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
                sws_freeContext(converter);
                avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
                avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
                return;
            }
            AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
            if (!pkt) {
                std::cerr << "Error allocating packet" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
            while (ret >= 0) {
                ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codec_ctx, pkt);
                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                    std::string a = av_err2str(ret);
                    break;
                }
                else if (ret < 0) {
                    wxMessageBox("Error during encoding");
                    wxMessageBox(av_err2str(ret));
                    av_packet_unref(pkt);
                    av_frame_free(&frame);
                    av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
                    sws_freeContext(converter);
                    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
                    avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
                    return;
                }

                // Write the packet to the output file
                av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, codec_ctx->time_base, stream->time_base);
                pkt->stream_index = stream->index;
                ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(format_ctx, pkt);
                av_packet_unref(pkt);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    std::cerr << "Error writing packet to output file: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
                    av_frame_free(&frame);
                    av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
                    sws_freeContext(converter);
                    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
                    avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Flush the encoder
    ret = avcodec_send_frame(codec_ctx, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error flushing encoder: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
        sws_freeContext(converter);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    while (ret >= 0) {
        AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
        if (!pkt) {
            std::cerr << "Error allocating packet" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codec_ctx, pkt);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            wxMessageBox("Error recieving packet");
            wxMessageBox(av_err2str(ret));
            break;
        }
        else if (ret < 0) {
            std::cerr << "Error during encoding: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
            av_packet_unref(pkt);
            av_frame_free(&frame);
            av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
            sws_freeContext(converter);
            avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
            avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
            return;
        }

        // Write the packet to the output file
        av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, codec_ctx->time_base, stream->time_base);
        pkt->stream_index = stream->index;
        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(format_ctx, pkt);
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            std::cerr << "Error writing packet to output file: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
            av_frame_free(&frame);
            av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
            sws_freeContext(converter);
            avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
            avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Write the trailer to the output file
    ret = av_write_trailer(format_ctx);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error writing trailer to output file: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
    }

    // Free all resources
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
    sws_freeContext(converter);
    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
    avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
}
```

** I know it is not the prettiest way to write this code, I just wanted to try and do something like that.

** This is an altered version of the function as the original one was inside class. I changed it so you could compile it, but it might has some errors if I forgot to change something

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- When encoding, it is recommended to initialize `codec_ctx` and use `avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, codec_ctx)` for copying the codec parameters from `codec_ctx` to `stream->codecpar`.
  `avcodec_parameters_to_context` is usually used when decoding video.
  We can see both usages in the [Transcoding tutorial](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial#transcoding-1).
- For 30pfs, use `framerate = { 30, 1}` instead of `framerate = { 1, 30}`.
- `sws_getContext` initialization is probably incorrect.
  We better get the source pixel format from `AVFrame`:
  `sws_getContext(codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, (AVPixelFormat)video.front().format, ...`
  After executing `sws_scale`, we better verify success: `if (ret != frame.height)` ... error...
- The arguments order of `av_rescale_q` is wrong, it should be: `converted_frame->pts = av_rescale_q(frame_count, codec_ctx->time_base, stream->time_base);`.
- We have to set `pkt->duration`:  `pkt->duration = av_rescale_q(1, codec_ctx->time_base, stream->time_base);`.
- When flushing the encoder, don't check `if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)`.

---

For testing, we may prepare 100 frames raw input video in `rgb24` pixel format using FFmpeg CLI:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=100 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 input.rgb24`

Then read the frames to a vector of `AVFrame` before executing `SaveVideo`.

---

Code sample:

```
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <cassert>
}


void SaveVideo(std::string& output_filename, std::vector<AVFrame> video)
{
    // Initialize FFmpeg
    //avformat_network_init();  //Not required.

    // Open the output file context
    AVFormatContext* format_ctx = nullptr;
    int ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&format_ctx, nullptr, nullptr, output_filename.c_str());
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error creating output context: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Open the output file
    ret = avio_open(&format_ctx->pb, output_filename.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening output file: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Create the video stream
    const AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!codec) {
        std::cerr << "Error finding H.264 encoder" << std::endl;
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    AVStream* stream = avformat_new_stream(format_ctx, codec);
    if (!stream) {
        std::cerr << "Error creating output stream" << std::endl;
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Set the stream parameters
    //stream->codecpar->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    //stream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    //stream->codecpar->width =video.front().width;
    //stream->codecpar->height = video.front().height;
    //stream->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    //stream->codecpar->bit_rate = 400000;
    ////AVRational framerate = { 1, 30};  //<--- the framerate is 0.0333fps instead of 30fps
    //AVRational framerate = { 30, 1};    //30 fps
    //stream->time_base = av_inv_q(framerate);

    // Open the codec context
    AVCodecContext* codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    //codec_ctx->codec_tag = 0;
    //codec_ctx->time_base = stream->time_base;
    //codec_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    //if (!codec_ctx) {
    //    std::cout << "Error allocating codec context" << std::endl;
    //    avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
    //    return;
    //}

    //I think to don't suppose to use avcodec_parameters_to_context when encoding - use avcodec_parameters_from_context instead
    //ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, stream->codecpar);
    //if (ret < 0) {
    //    std::cout << "Error setting codec context parameters: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
    //    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
    //    avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
    //    return;
    //}

    //Don't use avcodec_parameters_to_context when encoding - initialize codec_ctx and use avcodec_parameters_from_context to copy from codec_ctx to stream->codecpar.
    //1. Initialize codec_ctx
    //2. Open codec_ctx
    //3. Copy from codec_ctx to stream->codecpar using avcodec_parameters_from_context
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    codec_ctx->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    codec_ctx->width =video.front().width;
    codec_ctx->height = video.front().height;
    codec_ctx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    codec_ctx->bit_rate = 400000;
    //AVRational framerate = { 1, 30};  //<--- the framerate is 0.0333fps instead of 30fps
    AVRational framerate = { 30, 1};    //30 fps
    codec_ctx->time_base = av_inv_q(framerate);


    //<--- Place it after avcodec_parameters_to_context
    codec_ctx->codec_tag = 0;
    //codec_ctx->time_base = stream->time_base;
    codec_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    stream->time_base = codec_ctx->time_base;

    AVDictionary* opt = NULL;
    ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, &opt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cout << "Error opening codec: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, codec_ctx);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




    // Allocate a buffer for the frame data
    AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        std::cerr << "Error allocating frame" << std::endl;
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    frame->format = codec_ctx->pix_fmt;
    frame->width = codec_ctx->width;
    frame->height = codec_ctx->height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error allocating frame buffer: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Allocate a buffer for the converted frame data
    AVFrame* converted_frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!converted_frame) {
        std::cerr << "Error allocating converted frame" << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    converted_frame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    converted_frame->width = codec_ctx->width;
    converted_frame->height = codec_ctx->height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(converted_frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error allocating converted frame buffer: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Initialize the converter
    SwsContext* converter = sws_getContext(
        codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, (AVPixelFormat)video.front().format, //codec_ctx->pix_fmt,  <--- The source format comes from the input AVFrame
        codec_ctx->width, codec_ctx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
        SWS_BICUBIC, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr
    );
    if (!converter) {
        std::cerr << "Error initializing converter" << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Write the header to the output file
    ret = avformat_write_header(format_ctx, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error writing header to output file: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
        sws_freeContext(converter);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    // Iterate over the frames and write them to the output file
    int frame_count = 0;
    for (AVFrame& frame: video) {
        AVFrame *pFrame = &frame;
         {
            // Convert the frame to the output format
            ret = sws_scale(converter,
                frame.data, frame.linesize, 0, frame.height,
                converted_frame->data, converted_frame->linesize
            );

            if (ret != frame.height)  //<--- Check status of sws_scale
            {
                std::cerr << "sws_scale error: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
            }

            // Set the frame properties
            //converted_frame->pts = av_rescale_q(frame_count, stream->time_base, codec_ctx->time_base);
            converted_frame->pts = av_rescale_q(frame_count, codec_ctx->time_base, stream->time_base);  //<------- codec_ctx->time_base should come first.
            frame_count++;
            //converted_frame->time_base.den = codec_ctx->time_base.den;
            //converted_frame->time_base.num = codec_ctx->time_base.num;
            // Encode the frame and write it to the output
            ret = avcodec_send_frame(codec_ctx, converted_frame);
            if (ret < 0) {
                std::cerr << "Error sending frame for encoding: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;                
                av_frame_free(&pFrame);
                av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
                sws_freeContext(converter);
                avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
                avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
                return;
            }
            AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
            if (!pkt) {
                std::cerr << "Error allocating packet" << std::endl;
                return;
            }
            while (ret >= 0) {
                ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codec_ctx, pkt);
                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                    std::string a = std::to_string(ret);
                    break;
                }
                else if (ret < 0) {
                    std::cerr << "Error during encoding" << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
                    av_packet_unref(pkt);
                    av_frame_free(&pFrame);
                    av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
                    sws_freeContext(converter);
                    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
                    avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
                    return;
                }

                // Write the packet to the output file
                //av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, codec_ctx->time_base, stream->time_base);  <--- Do we need it???
                pkt->stream_index = stream->index;
                pkt->duration = av_rescale_q(1, codec_ctx->time_base, stream->time_base);   // <---- Set packet duration
                ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(format_ctx, pkt);
                av_packet_unref(pkt);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    std::cerr << "Error writing packet to output file: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
                    av_frame_free(&pFrame);
                    av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
                    sws_freeContext(converter);
                    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
                    avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Flush the encoder
    ret = avcodec_send_frame(codec_ctx, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error flushing encoder: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
        sws_freeContext(converter);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    while (ret >= 0) {
        AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
        if (!pkt) {
            std::cerr << "Error allocating packet" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codec_ctx, pkt);
        //if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {   <--- This part should not be in the encoder flushing loop
        //    std::cerr << "Error receiving packet: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
        //    break;
        //}
        //else if (ret < 0) {
        //    std::cerr << "Error during encoding: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
        //    av_packet_unref(pkt);
        //    av_frame_free(&frame);
        //    av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
        //    sws_freeContext(converter);
        //    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        //    avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        //    return;
        //}

        // Write the packet to the output file 
        //av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, codec_ctx->time_base, stream->time_base); <--- Do we need it???
        if (ret == 0)  //<--- Write packet if ret == 0
        {
            pkt->stream_index = stream->index;
            pkt->duration = av_rescale_q(1, codec_ctx->time_base, stream->time_base);   // <---- Set packet duration
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(format_ctx, pkt);
            av_packet_unref(pkt);
            if (ret < 0) {
                std::cerr << "Error writing packet to output file: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
                av_frame_free(&frame);
                av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
                sws_freeContext(converter);
                avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
                avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // Write the trailer to the output file
    ret = av_write_trailer(format_ctx);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error writing trailer to output file: " << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
    }

    // Free all resources
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_frame_free(&converted_frame);
    sws_freeContext(converter);
    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
    avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
}


//Building input:
//ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=100 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 input.rgb24

int main()
{
    std::string output_filename = "output_filename.mp4";

    std::vector<AVFrame> video;
    std::vector<AVFrame*> av_Frames;

    FILE *f = fopen("input.rgb24", "rb");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        AVFrame* pRGBFrame = av_frame_alloc();

        pRGBFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
        pRGBFrame->width = 192;
        pRGBFrame->height = 108;
        int sts = av_frame_get_buffer(pRGBFrame, 0);

        assert(sts == 0);
        assert((pRGBFrame->linesize[0] == 192*3));  //Make sure buffers are continuous in memory.

        fread(pRGBFrame->data[0], 1, 192*108*3, f);   //Read RGB

        video.push_back(*pRGBFrame);
        av_Frames.push_back(pRGBFrame);
    }
    fclose(f);

    SaveVideo(output_filename, video);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        av_frame_free(&av_Frames[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine now when saving small amount of frames. But something weird happens when i try to save a vector with larger number of frames. When the frame_count reaches 316 exactly it somehow stops working (even with diff inputs). The `ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(format_ctx, pkt);` returns -22 and although `ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codec_ctx, pkt);` returns 0 the data of the packet is null. Do you maybe know why something like that might happen?

Comment: In addition, when i save a video with around 200 frames, it saves it in 5880 fps. Do you know why is that?

Comment: I tested my example with 10000 frames, and didn't find any issues. Try executing my example with `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10000 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 input.rgb24` and `for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)`. Please execute my code sample as is first...

Comment: I tried that and it still returned that error, and when I ran it with smaller number of frames it saved it with 5970 fps

Comment: We are probably using different versions of FFmpeg libraries. I am using `ffmpeg-5.1.2-full_build-shared` (pre-built x64 GPL version). The video encoder found by `avcodec_find_encoder` is `libx264`. I am also using Windows 10 (and Visual Studio 2019).

Comment: Thank u so much for your help, i figured it out. I had a problem caused by the `avformat_write_header` as it changed the time_base of the stream which caused a different behavior than I expected.